# Android: OnClick method for Button doesn't respond

Tags: android

I didn't have this problem until now. I don't know what is the problem here because in the same layout i have several buttons and only buttons which are in LinearLayout won't respond.

This is the layout where my buttons won't respond onClick (**EDITED)**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:background="@drawable/texture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_first_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_last_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_first_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_last_name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/input_age"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_button"
            style="@style/MyCustomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edit_button"
            android:onClick="run"
            android:text="@string/save_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_button"
            style="@style/MyCustomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
            android:text="@string/edit_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            style="@style/MyCustomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/save_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/save_button"
            android:text="@string/delete_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_birthday_date"
            style="@style/MyCustomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cake_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_movie"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_books"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_tech"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_container1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:clickable="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_body_care"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_clothes"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_accessories"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_container2"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_games"
                style="@style/MyCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edit_button"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cake_image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edit_birthday_date"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_birthday_date"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/birthday_cake" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/turning_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cake_image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cake_image"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cake_image" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have set for every linear layout visibility when one button which is working is clicked to visible, so i think that is not the problem.

This is the code in java:

```
if (getMovieCategory.equals("movies")) {
            buttonCategoryMovie.setText("MOVIES");
            buttonCategoryMovie.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            buttonCategoryMovie.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_cancelar, 0, 0, 0);
            buttonCategoryMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String movies = "movies";
                    dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, movies);
                }
            });
        } else {
            buttonCategoryMovie.setText("MOVIES");
            buttonCategoryMovie.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            buttonCategoryMovie.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_add, 0, 0, 0);
            buttonCategoryMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dbh.deleteMovies(getMovieCategory);
                }
            });
        }
```

Here everything is working except onClick. I'm getting no errors. My button doesn't respond on click.

Comment: Post the Activity's code.

Comment: Both Listener not working ?

Comment: Post your full source code of activity here.

Comment: suggestion: add android:weight_sum=3 to your linearlayouts.

Comment: Guys this is still not working, i mean the button doesn't respond on click and there is no error. I have tried everything you suggested me. Setting onClickListener out side the if condition, setting linearLayouts clickable state to true, but noting.

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints to see if the onClick is actually responding? Breakpoints at dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, movies); and dbh.deleteMovies(getMovieCategory); for example, and see if the program actually does/doesn't step into them?

Comment: Before that i have set only onClick without any code inside and i have already two states when button is pressed and when button is normal and without anything i should see that states changes when i click on button, but it won't changed.

Comment: See my answer then. I suspect that the problem is in having two listeners for the same button.

Comment: @mjp66 i have edited my layout so you can see my whole layout if i'm making there maybe some mistake because i have tried you're code and it still doesn't respond.

Comment: I think I figured it out, see my edit in a few minutes. The main problem is that your code makes it difficult to understand what you're actually trying to do ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.You're coding with a lot of redundancy and risking introducing errors, some of which may not be immediately obvious. Here's a leaner and clearer version of your posted code sample, using one onClick method to handle your if(){else} conditions.

```
buttonCategoryMovie.setText("MOVIES");
buttonCategoryMovie.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

buttonCategoryMovie.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
    getMovieCategory.equals("movies") ? R.drawable.ic_cancelar : R.drawable.ic_add, 0,0,0
);

buttonCategoryMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (getMovieCategory.equals("movies")) {
            String movies = "movies";
            dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, movies);
        } else {
            dbh.deleteMovies(getMovieCategory);
        }
    }
});
```

**EDIT 1:** I mistakenly left out your `String movies = "movies"` and have added it back in. If you're only going to use this String once, to pass it as a parameter for `dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, movies)`, then you could simply call `dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, "movies")` and delete `String movies = "movies"`

**EDIT 2:** Without seeing your entire source code, I don't know if you're at all changing the value of `getMovieCategory` somewhere. If not, then the below sample will change it on every click of the button (once you launch the app to test the sample, your `buttonCategoryMovie` will be a generic Button; once you start clicking the button, it should toggle between showing your `R.drawable.ic_cancelar` and `R.drawable.ic_add` resources. If the button toggles between these two drawables, then you at least know that the button is in fact receiving the onClick.

Remember that, if the value of `getMovieCategory` doesn't change on each click, your button will always perform only one of the sets of onClick actions and it'll look like nothing's happening.

If it works for you as I've described, then you're on your way ;)

```
buttonCategoryMovie.setText("MOVIES");
buttonCategoryMovie.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

buttonCategoryMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (getMovieCategory.equals("movies")) {
            getMoviesCategory = "not movies"; // this is here just to test
            buttonCategoryMovie.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_cancelar, 0, 0, 0);
            String movies = "movies";
            dbh.updateCategoryMovies(birthdayId, movies);
        } else {
            getMoviesCategory = "movies"; // this is here just to test
            buttonCategoryMovie.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_add, 0, 0, 0);
            dbh.deleteMovies(getMovieCategory);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have solved the problem with getting the buttons outside of linear layouts, but you're code did help me organising my code to be reasonable. I have one more problem with sql database. Is sql familiar to you?

Comment: Glad it helped and thanks! :). The rules here frown upon straying from the topic of the original question, so the best thing to do for your sql problem is to post a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

try by handling setOnClickListener out side the if condition.

Comment: But i need it in if condition, because i have two statements where i want to do something if one condition is true and second where i want to something else with onClickListener.

Comment: You should use the same listener and check what to do **inside** your `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `android:visibility="gone"` to `android:visibility="visible"` in your LinearLayout.

And again add `android:clickable="true"` to your LinearLayout

Comment: I have changed that programmatically when some code is executed because i don't need those buttons to be visible while user chose edit button.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic Then handle your onClick listeners outside the if statements as suggested by **MFP**